# Connecting MS-SQL with initial catalog

Tags: sql, database, r

I suceeded to connect MS-SQL in R by using following code

```
#get JDBC Driver
drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", "C:/Program Files (x86)/JDBC/sqljdbc_4.0/kor/sqljdbc4.jar")
#connect to DB
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://ip", "id", "pwd")`
```

However, there are many catalogs in MS-SQL Server. I don't know how to specify initial catalog when it connects to MS-SQL.

If there's a catalog named 'MYCAT' and a table named 'MYTAB'. How can I access the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), the general connection string to MS-SQL server is :

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

For example, Assuming that your DB server is  local:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=MYCAT;integratedSecurity=true;
```

Connect on the default port to the local server and database MYCAT .

Comment: @KeithPark gald that this helps. I am preparing a new R package to access SQL server. Do you use JDBC in production?

Comment: I just use JDBC for proving concepts. If my scenario works pretty well, it will be used for production system. I'm looking foward to your new R package!

Comment: Which scenario do you prepare? Reading.writing? data volume? can you give more context please?

Comment: Our DBMS stores 500GB/year. The data is from Telematrics system, field claim(warranty), and sales data. One of my customer wants me to find out any information from it. Therefore, most of my work will be related to reading data from DB. I'm about to use those data for finding out association rules and clustering.

Comment: @KeithPark Hi. You can check maybe check the beta vesion of my [rsqlserver](https://github.com/agstudy/rsqlserver) package.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like it works as a server and it allows sql connection with the other sql apllication. I think it might help if I need to use R as a production system.